# Aggregate operation oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and I need to find the person with the highest value.

TABLE1

> ```
> NAME           ID
> --------------- ---------------
>   MIKE          101
>   MIKE          102
>   BETTY         103
>   BETTY         104
>   BETTY         105
>   TIM           106
> ```

TABLE2

> ```
> ID                VALUE
> --------       --------------
> 101            12
> 102            10
> 103            20
> 104            20
> 105            10
> 106             5
> ```

I can write a select statement that will give a result of name and values:

> ```
>   SELECT name, value
>     FROM table1, table2
>     WHERE table1.id = table.id;
> ```

```
  NAME    VALUE
 -----   ----------
  MIKE          12
  MIKE          10
  BETTY         20
  BETTY         20
  BETTY         10
  TIM           5
```

Now I need to aggregate the  values of the rows with equal names and I can not figure it out.  Am I going about it the correct way?

Comment: You want the person(s) having the highest value, or the highest value per person?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this :

```
select a.name,max(b.value) as value
from table1 a
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
group by a.name
```

Anyway, you tagged mysql and oracle in the question. Luckily, this sql works in both. But you have to remove one of these two tags, to make sure which dbms are you use.

Comment: ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "B"."VALUE": invalid identifier
I got this error

Comment: @user3137110 That's mean you don't have column `value` in table2. Can you provide how your table structure looks like?

Comment: My mistake I mislabeled the attribute.  It worked.  What are  you doing when you  write  "a.name" and "b.value" ?

Comment: @user3137110 a and b is aliases for table. It's same like `from table1 a,table2 b where a.id = b.id`

Answer (score 1):

Use this.. and since your column names are unique, you don't need any alias.

```
select name, max(value) as MaxValue
from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
group by name
```